# Bootcamp - How to always load the boot selector screen on start up

Tags: mac, bootcamp

Is there something I can do so that when I turn on my computer the boot selector screen shows up, without me having to press alt.
I've seen this answered, but that was 2012 and it doesn't work anymore.